# How to in SimpleScheme get DOM data from Form in Meteor

Tags: forms, meteor

Hi Im trying to have a simple form in meteor where I have values that stay the same and one value that changes all the time with a random generator. However when I sent the data, the form in send empty data or just 'true'.

See Example

[image: 1]

I'm trying to get the simple form to sent the random generated data

Example 1.1

[image: 2]

Comment: You need to share more code, but you are adding an HTML command inside the schema. This is now a good practice.

Comment: Thanks, but no data is coming out